# JavaFX setOnClosedRequest in Dialog not fired

Tags: javafx

I have a Problem with my JavaFX app. It is devided in to parts - a main Stage and a Stage as a Dialog. When i close the main stage setonclosedrequest is fired as expected, but setoncloserequest of the dialog Stage is never fired. What i do wrong ? Here is my code:

Main App:

```
public class TestApp extends Application{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLDialogLoader loader = new FXMLDialogLoader("de/pasa/fxml/Dialog.fxml");
        loader.setController(new DialogController(primaryStage));
        loader.loadPrimaryStage(primaryStage, "Main App");
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(e->{
            System.out.println("Do something before Close");
        });
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class DialogController implements Initializable{
    @FXML private Button bOpen;
    private Stage parentStage = null;
    public DialogController(Stage parentStage) {
        this.parentStage=parentStage;
    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        bOpen.setOnAction(e->{
            FXMLDialogLoader loader=new FXMLDialogLoader("de/pasa/fxml/Test.fxml", parentStage);
            Stage dlgStage=loader.loadDialog();

            dlgStage.setOnCloseRequest(t->{
                //never reached - not fired, why ?
                System.out.println("Do something before Dialog closed");
            });
        });
    }
}
```

FXMLLoader:

```
public class FXMLDialogLoader {
    private String _fxmlPath=null;
    private String _title=null;
    private Object _controller=null;
    private ResourceBundle _bundle=null;
    private Stage _parentStage=null;
    private Stage _primaryStage=null;
    private Stage stage=null;
    private StageStyle _style=null;
    private String _iconPath=null;
    private LoggerEX _log = LoggerEX.getLogger(FXMLDialogLoader.class);
    public FXMLDialogLoader(String fxmlPath){
        this(fxmlPath,null);
    }
    public FXMLDialogLoader(String fxmlPath,Stage parentStage){
        this(fxmlPath,parentStage,"Dialog",null,null,StageStyle.UTILITY);
    }
    public FXMLDialogLoader(String fxmlPath,Stage parentStage,String title,Object controller,ResourceBundle bundle,StageStyle style){
        _fxmlPath=fxmlPath;
        _parentStage=parentStage;
        _controller=controller;
        _bundle=bundle;
        _title=title;
        _style=style;
    }
    public Stage loadDialog(){
        FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(_fxmlPath));
        loader.setController(_controller);
        loader.setResources(_bundle);
        try {
            Parent root=loader.load();
            Scene scene=new Scene(root);
            if(_primaryStage==null){
                stage=new Stage();
            }
            else{
                stage=_primaryStage;
            }
            if(_iconPath!=null){
                stage.getIcons().add(new Image(new FileInputStream(new File(_iconPath))));
            }
            stage.setTitle(_title);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            if(_primaryStage==null){
                stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            }
            stage.initStyle(_style);
            if(_primaryStage==null){
                stage.initOwner(_parentStage);
            }
            if(_primaryStage==null){
                stage.showAndWait();
            }
            else{
                stage.show();
            }
            stage.centerOnScreen();
        } 
        catch(IOException ex){          
            ex.printStackTrace();
            _log.error(ex);
        }
        return stage;
    }
    public Stage getDialogStage(){
        return stage;
    }
    public Stage loadPrimaryStage(Stage primaryStage,String title){
        return loadPrimaryStage(primaryStage,title,null);
    }
    public Stage loadPrimaryStage(Stage primaryStage,String title,String iconPath){
        _primaryStage=primaryStage;
        setTitle(title);
        setIconPath(iconPath);
        setStageStyle(StageStyle.DECORATED);
        _primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
        loadDialog();
        return _primaryStage;
    }
    public void setIconPath(String iconPath){
        _iconPath=iconPath;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title){
        _title=title;
    }
    public void setStageStyle(StageStyle style){
        _style=style;
    }
    public void setController(Object controller){
        _controller=controller;
    }
    public void setResourceBundle(ResourceBundle bundle){
        _bundle=bundle;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to SET a closing behaviour or do you want to add something to the default closing behaviour?

Comment: When i push the x Button on the Dialog Stage i want to do something . e.g. save some data into external properties or db. but setoncloserequest does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `showAndWait()` to display the dialog, which, as the method name implies, waits until the dialog is dismissed before returning. Only after the dialog is dismissed do you then register the `onCloseRequest` handler: by then it is too late to process the event.

Comment: Yes it works. I tried to register the oncloserequest before showandwait - and it works. Thanks for your answer.